# Digital / Physical goods on in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I’m developing a Marketplace App of the courses for the Learning Purposes and we don’t have any kind of control over uploading of Physical content( CDs, DVDs, Hard Copy of the book, etc. ) or the Digital Content (Videos, Audios, Ebooks, etc.) on the courses uploaded by the seller for the consumers to purchase.

So could you please suggest what kind of payment method should we use apart from In-App purchases?

If we are bound to use In-App purchase then how should we implement it in our App and also we have following queries to clear our doubts for the monetization of the app.

- Could we add n number of courses dynamically having digital and physical content with In-App Purchases implemented? In our app the courses limit is not fixed, it can be 5000, 10000 or 100000.
- Will it be possible for the sellers to provide any kind of discounts for the existing courses?
- How could we manage(addition or deletion) the courses dynamically with In-App purchases?

I researched on google but no solution was found. Some solutions were found on StackOverflow but we can't find  proper guidelines for our queries. Thanks :)

Comment: Find all answers in regards to InApp purchases here: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Comment: why down vote man ? I already read all instructions provided by your link. there is no any instruction regarding to my queries there is no proper solutions for my content which contain both physical and digital goods read my question properly. @shallowThought

Comment: I did not downvote. Just wanted to provide you with a link that answers all your questions. Oddies answer sums it up.

Comment: ohk but can you please suggest any other way to do for selling on marketplace content  which contain both physical and as well as digital. @shallowThought

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be partly an opinion-based question, but with regards to IAPs there are a couple of important rules:

1) For **all** digital goods, you have to use in-app purchases, otherwise Apple will not approve your app. There are different approaches to your problem. You could either let people buy credits with IAPs and then dynamically create the store on your own. Then you have 100% control over discounts etc.) Or each product will be its own IAP, but this will create lots of "overhead" as you have to get approval for each IAP.

2) For physical goods you are **not** allowed to use in-app purchases. There you have to find a 3rd party payment provider.